# Silent installation of shell script using bash file

Tags: shell-script

I have a setup file for Linux which is in shell script format. I'm trying to perform a silent installation by writing a bash script. When I directly access the script I'm unable to suppress the setup window. How can I perform this installation silently?

-------Edit-------

I am new to linux and bash scripting.

It is using an Java installer. And once the script file is ran in terminal the result is

[image]

The installer window is as follows

[image]

I want to install this application without any GUI by silent installation.

Comment: It's not the shell script you need to work on, it's the installer... Add options to the installer for hiding the gui, not the script...

Comment: What are you trying to setup?

Comment: Can you please provide the details as to what installer you're trying to do this for? If you add the details then the Q can be reopened so that user's can attempt to help.

Comment: @slm Hi glenn, I have edited the question and added few screenshots to that. Hope this helps in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @Sarat - what is the name of this software you're attempting to install? I would also run that command line using something like `/path/to/app --help` to see if there aren't any switches like `--unattended`. What you're asking for isn't really a feature of provided by the OS/Shell, it's more of a feature provided by the actual GUI you're attempting to run.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed and quite likely on linux, that the installer simply uses a DISPLAY connection to your X11 screen, as a very quick and dirty fix, start a second X server on DISPLAY :1

```
X :1 &
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Now the installer should honour the new DISPLAY environment.

Not exactly silent though ;)